# What is the past participle of the word 'prove'?

Tags: grammar

Is it "I have proved..."

Or

"I have proven..."?

Or are both versions correct?

Comment: If this were in ELL it would be closed as look it up in a dictionary

Answer (score 2):

As a past participle, both versions are correct, and used roughly equally often. See the usage note in the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prove). But when used as an adjective (*e.g., a proven technique*), there is a very strong preference for *proven*.

Note that this usage note is in an American dictionary; [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+proved%3Aeng_us_2012%2Chas+proven%3Aeng_us_2012%2Chas+proved%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Chas+proven%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20proved%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20proven%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20proved%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20proven%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows that *proved* is still the most common past participle in British English, although even in British English, *proven* is usually [used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+proven%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ca+proved%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ca+proven%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ca+proved%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20proven%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20proved%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20proven%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20proved%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) as the adjective.